# Solutions for transition from small scale to mid-scale MySQL database

Tags: mysql, database-design, scalability

I'm studying up on the future of the database I maintain. Right now we have one database server running MySQL using InnoDB and MyISAM tables. I'm watching the metrics closely and I can see that this will not be sustainable forever. Where does one go next? I have reviewed solutions like Cassandra, but I want to stick to an SQL approach so I'm not sure about that. I have also reviewed NDB cluster and federated database solutions, but I've noticed no one has anything good to say about those. Basically, I looking for advice on intermediate solutions. We do not yet need a vast multi-node array operating on tens of DB servers, but one server is about to reach its limit. I don't want to just throw another server on the pile without making sure that the DB architecture at hand benefits well from the extra power. What do you guys suggest for when it is time to move beyond a single server and how to manage this transition. Thank you to anyone who can help.

Edit to better explain: At present, we have about a hundred tables. We run many join operations to gather the data the end user needs to see, such that most of our queries join at least two tables to complete any operation. The data set is not too big yet, only a few hundred Megs, but the data is accessed in such a way that each table has a few writes everyday, the heaviest of which has about a thousand writes a day. We probably have about a few hundred thousand reads a day too, so read do outnumber writes about 9 to 1.

Comment: Well, what's the usage like? Lots of reads? Lots of writes?

Comment: @ceejayoz I added some more info. I'll start gathering more specific number information.

Comment: If you're mostly reads, a read-only replicated slave server that you send some of the read queries to will do a world of good. No need to go into the deep end with Cassandra, NDB, federation, or vast arrays. Caching may help, too.

Comment: @ceejayoz Yes, caching is clearly a step I need to further consider. Any good suggestions on reading material for read only slave servers and where to begin with that?

Comment: This is the type of question that the DBA's can probably answer better.  http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'd suggest making sure your hardware is adequate for the database.  If you have enough memory, your database would be accessing rows from cached memory rather than the disk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First Solutions:

- Indices go a LONG way
- Use profiling software to find your slow queries and optimize them
- Depending on your hosting company you can usually update the RAM/CPU of the server

Second Solutions:

- Split your reads and your writes into two databases. (I don't know if you're using PHP or not but PHP has a plugin that will automatically split them for you without having to change any of your code http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlnd-ms.rwsplit.php)
- Use software like memcache to store database information that is frequently queried but not frequently updated